# How can I modify my CPAN area to require only one directory in my @INC path?

Tags: perl, cpan

I have installed a bunch of CPAN modules in my area. It seems that each package wants to be installed somewhere different under my PREFIX.

In my case, I have to use this:

```
setenv CPAN_DIR <my root>/perl-5.12.2_cpan

setenv PERLLIB $CPAN_DIR/install/lib64/site_perl/x86_64-linux:$CPAN_DIR/install/lib/5.12.2:$CPAN_DIR/install/lib/site_perl/x86_64-linux:$CPAN_DIR/install/lib/site_perl:$CPAN_DIR/install/lib/perl5:$CPAN_DIR/install/lib/site_perl/5.12.2:$CPAN_DIR/install/lib/site_perl/5.12.2/x86_64-linux
```

I'd like to be able to setup a package 'release' area that requires only:

```
setenv PERLLIB <one dir>
```

or

```
use lib '<one dir>';
```

Surely this is not a novel idea. What's the trick?

Comment: Why are you fiddling with your PERLLIB at runtime in the first place? This is something you should generally leave alone, but if you really want to alter it, configure it when you compile and install Perl itself.

Comment: What arguments are you passing to `Makefile.PL` and `Build.PL` when you install modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use lib` and PERL5LIB both add not only the directories you specify, but the expected version or arch subdirectories under them.  Are you sure you actually have a problem here?

If so, can you show an example where use lib is not working, including perl -V output?

Comment: you're right. I've been in the habit of using PERLLIB which doesn't work. PERL5LIB and use lib do.